Fourier transform on half spaces
The Fourier transform is known to be a very powerful tool to solve linear PDE's. I read that this is above all the case when solving a linear PDE on the whole space or on some half space.
Questions:

Is there a difference between the Fourier transform on the whole space and the half space? If so what is the difference?
Is it important which half space I consider? Take e.g. $(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and $(1,\infty)\times (0,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. What would be the difference between the Fourier transforms on these half spaces?

